setlocale: LC_CTYPE: cannot change locale (UTF-8): No such file or directory on Amazon Linux 2
   ,     #_
   ~\_  ####_        Amazon Linux 2
  ~~  \_#####\
  ~~     \###|       AL2 End of Life is 2025-06-30.
  ~~       \#/ ___
   ~~       V~' '->
    ~~~         /    A newer version of Amazon Linux is available!
      ~~._.   _/
         _/ _/       Amazon Linux 2023, GA and supported until 2028-03-15.
       _/m/'           https://aws.amazon.com/linux/amazon-linux-2023/

-bash: warning: setlocale: LC_CTYPE: cannot change locale (UTF-8): No such file or directory


Now I did look this up and solutions seem to indicate that you need to write to /etc/environment. How to fix this error on Amazon Linux 2? I am using CDK to launch an instance
